# Processing a form created by dynamic php/mySql Setup

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I run a script to create an order form, this is just a really small sample. I'm not so good with PHP and dynamic forms. It pulls data from mysql database.

```
<td>
<h3>Round Cuts</h3>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($round_cuts)){
$round_box_value = @$row["meat_names"];
$round_box_value_name = @$row["meat_names"];
echo " <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"round_box_value\" value=\"$round_box_value_name\">     $round_box_value_name";
echo "<br>";
}?>
</td>
```

I've ever really only built basic contact forms, how could I process a dynamic form like this. If all else fails I would just take all the possible elements and program this like it was a not dynamic. There must be a better way though.

Even a link to a website would be helpful. I've been searching for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `@` to suppress errors? And if you've processed static forms, what is the difference between dynamic ones? They are processed exactly the same way.

Comment: change the name to round_box_value[] then you get a nice array in the $_POST to loop through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your table as a primary key of `id`

Start off with a minor change to your checkboxes:

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($round_cuts)){
  echo sprintf('<label><input type="checkbox" name="round_box_value[]" value="%s"> %s</label><br>', $row['id'], $row['meat_names']);
}
?>
```

The name now has an `[]` at the end to tell php it's an array of values + I've wrapped the checkbox in a label for convenience.

Then when you process the form, you can simply iterate through round_box_value like so

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['round_box_value'] as $id) {
  // $id is the table reference from your previous table
}

// or query all the rows selected
$ids = array_map('intval', $_POST['round_box_value']); // "basic" sql injection handler
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(",", $ids).")";
```

should produce something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (2,5,7)
```

Comment: It worked mixing your code in and a little trail and error got me to the solution. Appreciate the help.